# Adding Sign In/Sign Up into rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, api, authentication, rubygems

I am trying to integrate  **SignIn / SignUp**  into my rails application. 
 Currently i have Two API's for  **Sign In and Sign Up** (Maintained by other team). These API's will take care of validations and stuff at their end and send me `success/failure` response back.

I am aware that we can have a custom SignIn/SignUp form and send the details to that particular API's. 
I want to know the best and if possible easiest way to integrate SignIn/SignUp page into my App. I am not sure of any other cool way to do it ? like hosted library kind of or anything ?

Comment: Depending on the nature of the API (ldap, saml) you may want to look at `Devise`, a Rails authentication gem (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Comment: @Vasseurth 
i am aware of devise, but in my case does devise help ? as with devise we can have our own authentication system ..which i dont want it..and can you also mention how does nature of API will matter

Comment: Devise has some add ons that let it function not as your own authentication system, but through a different authentication system (e.g. Devise OAuth can let you sign in with a Google Account). The nature of the API would determine which add on to use. Does the API use LDAP? SAML? Can it be used with OAuth?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, go with Devise. You'll be able to do whatever you want.

Comment: can you explain a bit on how can i use devise for my use case ?